# How to find the number of form elements that are getting passed to e.parameter in GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

In Google App Scripts (GAS), I want to be able to add and remove TextBox and TextArea elements to a FlexTable (that's being used as a form) and not worry about how many there are.  I've named the text elements based on a counter to make this process easier.

So, is there a way to get the number of inputs (TextBox + TextArea) passed to e.parameter after the form is submitted?

Here's the relevant code from the FlexTable:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var flex = app.createFlexTable().setId('myFlex');

  var counter = 0;
  var row_counter = 0;

  ...

  var firstnameLabel = app.createLabel('Your FIRST Name');
  var firstnameTextBox = app.createTextBox().setWidth(sm_width).setName('input' + counter).setText(data[counter]);
  flex.setWidget(row_counter, 1, firstnameLabel);
  flex.setWidget(row_counter, 2, firstnameTextBox);
  row_counter++;
  counter++;

  var lastnameLabel = app.createLabel('Your LAST Name');
  var lastnameTextBox = app.createTextBox().setWidth(sm_width).setName('input' + counter).setText(data[counter]);
  flex.setWidget(row_counter, 1, lastnameLabel);
  flex.setWidget(row_counter, 2, lastnameTextBox);
  row_counter++;
  counter++;

  ...

  var submitButton = app.createButton('Submit Proposal');
  flex.setWidget(row_counter, 2, submitButton);

  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('saveProposal');
  handler.addCallbackElement(flex);
  submitButton.addClickHandler(handler);

  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setSize('100%', '100%');
  scroll.add(flex);
  app.add(scroll);
  return app;
}
```

And here's the code for the ClickHandler (notice that I currently have 39 elements in my FlexTable):

```
function saveProposal(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var userData = [];
  var counter = 39;

   for(var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    var input_name = 'input' + i;
    userData[i] = e.parameter[input_name];
  }
```

So, is there a way to get the number of elements (in this case 39) without manually counting them and assigning this value to a variable?

I'm new at this stuff and I'd appreciate your help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a [hidden widget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/hidden) in your `doGet()` function that will hold the `counter` value like this :

```
var hidden = app.createHidden('counterValue',counter);// don't forget to add this widget as a callBackElement to your handler variable (handler.addCallBackElement(hidden))
```

then in the handler function simply use

```
var counter = Number(e.parameter.counterValue);// because the returned value is actually a string, as almost any other widget...
```

If you want to see this value while debugging you can replace it momentarily with a textBox...

Comment: Thanks so much Serge insas; it worked perfectly!  One follow up question (because I'm a novice)...  when can I reference a value in e.parameter using the dot notation (e.parameter.counterValue) and when can I reference a value using an array (e.parameter[input1])?

Comment: sorry, site was in read only for a while ! use square brackets only when you need to build the name with 2 or more elements, for example if you set names like `name1, name2, name3` and want to use a `for` loop you can build it using `e.parameter["name"+i]` where i is incremented in the loop. Or if you are using a variable as name : for example `e.parameter[varName[1]]` where `varName[1]` would be an array element.In every other case where name is known and  defined a plain string is ok

Answer (score 0):

You can search for `arguments`  array based object.

```
function foo(x) {
     console.log(arguments.length); // This will print 7.
}
foo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) // Sending 7 parameters to function.
```

Comment: This wont work in the context of this code. The object in the clickHandler function is something like that : `{parameter={clientY=39, clientX=177, eventType=click, ctrl=false, counterValue=18, meta=false, source=u466870005418, button=1, alt=false, screenY=156, screenX=180, shift=false, y=35, x=173}}` (random example)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop.

```
var i = 0;
var userData = [];

while (e.parameter['input' + i] != undefined) {
  userData[i] = e.parameter['input' + i];
  i++;
};
```

OR:

```
var i = 0;
var userData = [];
var input_name = 'input0';

while (e.parameter[input_name] != undefined) {
  userData[i] = e.parameter[input_name];
  i++;
  input_name = 'input' + i;
};
```